# how to create a node from a string literal in rapidjson?

Tags: rapidjson

I want to create a JSON node from a string literal in rapidjson, my code is as follows(which doesn't work of cause):

```
inline rapidjson::Value to_json(const std::string& myStr) {
    auto result = rapidjson::Value(rapidjson::kStringType);
    result.SetString(myStr);
    return result;
}
```

I remember that Jackson's APIs are so nice that you can create a String node by `TextNode.valueOf(myStr)`.

Is there a similar way to create a JSON node from string literal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an allocator. And if you have defined `RAPIDJSON_HAS_STDSTRING=1`, you can simply:

```
Document d;
std::string s = "...";
Value v(s, d.GetAllocator());
```

Comment: Thanks, I just enabled string by adding `#define RAPIDJSON_HAS_STDSTRING 1` and it works, I'm using rapidjson in one of my projects https://github.com/algohub/judge-engine